# Laravel on AWS server doesn't return Set-Cookie header

Tags: laravel, nginx, cookies, amazon-cloudfront, laravel-sanctum

## In the development environment

I installed `laravel/sanctum` and accessed `/api/csrf-cookie` in the local php server, `Set-Cookie` headers existed in the response and the cookies (session and xsrf-token) were properly set.

As the port numbers in the development environment are different between the front end and the back end, I also use `fruitcake/laravel-cors` and add the headers to allow CORS. The request from the browser, the front end, was succeeded too.

## In the cloud environment

I deployed these projects to CloudFront. When I accessed `example.cloudfront.net/api/csrf-cookie`, `Set-Cookie` headers didn't exist in the response. I also tried from the front end, but no cookie was found. All routes are working correctly, but only `Set-Cookie` is not working. CloudFront routes are here.

**CloudFront Routes**

```
example.cloudfront.net/ -> S3 (nuxt static generated site)

example.cloudfront.net/api/csrf-cookie -> ALB -> EC2 (laravel on nginx)
```

**Env**

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=example.cloudfront.net
#SESSION_DOMAIN=[local ip without the port] # works in local
```

How to get the cookies from the cloud environment?

Comment: What do you see in the browser network tab response?

Answer (score 0):

I set `Forward Cookies` to `All` in CloudFront, then everything goes well.